# Prevent subclass outside of a header file

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have the following three class defined in a .h file:

```
class Base
{ // number of pure virtual functions };

class Derived1 : public Base
{ // number of pure virtual functions };

class Derived2 : public Base
{ // number of pure virtual functions };
```

I want users of this header file to only subclass Derived1 or Derived2.  I want to prevent users from subclass'ing Base.  I "could" have used the keyword "final" for class Base, but that would prevent me from subclassing in my header file.  I need to have all the above classes in the header file as a user needs to provide definitions of methods in Base and DerivedX classes.

I am thinking of something like limiting the scope of inheritance to within a header file (similar to a static variable).  Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could make the Base constructor private and have those two classes friends

Comment: I really dislike this kind of thinking. Base classes have no concept or notion of the derived classes that inherit from them, so why why why should they be able to ban the derived classes' existence?!

Comment: +1 on Lightness, I would change something in the design if I were you. But it's probably off-topic for the question

Comment: I get the sense that you are trying to use the wrong approach to solve something. How are `Derevied1` and `Derived2` benefitting by deriving from `Base` and what harm would arise if other classes derived from `Base`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't base classes already need to have a notion of allowing derived classes? e.g. providing virtual destructors, or if the base class derives from another class, possibly using virtual inheritance in case someone creates a diamond later...

Comment: @jamesdlin: True, though I'd argue that those are _abstraction leaks_ similar to what this OP proposes.

Answer (score 17):

You could make the `Base` constructor private and have those two classes friends, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
private:
    Base() {}
    friend class Derived1;
    friend class Derived2;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
};

int main() {

    Derived1 obj;
    Base obj2; // Error

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/NUWad0

Also notice: copy/move constructor of base class should probably also be private. I'm not adding the code to focus on the main proposal but you should think about it too.

---

Edit with regard to friend constructors.

First off: you cannot reference the members of an incomplete type before its definition is seen by the compiler (it works as a one-time pass and there might be some overload resolution involved). This means the following won't work:

```
class Derived1;
class Derived2;

class Base
{
private:
    Base() {}
    friend Derived1::Derived1(); // Error - incomplete type 'Derived1' in nested name specifier
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    public:
    Derived1() {};
};

...
```

and you cannot forward declare a base class (you wouldn't know how much space to allocate for a derived object):

```
class Base;

class Derived1 : public Base // Error: base class has incomplete type
{
    public:
    Derived1() {};
};

class Base
{
private:
    Base() {}
    friend Derived1::Derived1();
};

...
```

therefore in your specific case you'd better off with a friend class access unless you want to modify something in your design.

Comment: This is how I'd do it too. Just a note though, I'd remove `using namespace std` since it's bad practice and doesn't do anything in this code anyway.

Comment: @Rapptz I agree, it was just a quick code snippet but it's good to avoid that. Thanks

Comment: It does not prevent sub classing Base !!

Comment: @omid that is correct, I just tried it out.  I can define "class Derived3 : public Base   { };  ".  I would have liked it if the compiler would have / could have flagged this as an error.  However, the compiler does generate an error if I try to instantiate Derived3.  I guess this is good enough.

Comment: @MarcoA. Can you please elaborate on the syntax of your suggestion.  Do you mean instead of "friend class Derived1;" in class Base, use "friend class Derived1:Derived1();".

Comment: Some comments: Make sure you get all ctors (remember special functions are automatically defined under common circumstances, so sometimes you need to explicitly delete them with `=delete;`). Avoid having a non-trivial special-function if you can help it: `=default;` can be trivial, `{}` never is. Performance will thank you. Also, strictly speaking it does not prevent inappropriate sub-classing, though instantiation of such rogue derived classes.

Comment: Copy/move constructor of base class should also be private.

Comment: I agree, I'll add that to the answer. Thanks!